# Return to the same route after login REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am doing firebase authentication in my application,

In my App.js I am firing this method..

```
store.dispatch(isLoggedIn())
```

and this is what `isLoggedIn()` do

```
export const isLoggedIn = () => dispatch => {
  API.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))
    } else {
      dispatch(setCurrentUser({}))
    }
  })
}
```

and in App.js I have

```
store.dispatch(isLoggedIn())

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute
                exact
                path="/stats"
                component={Stats}
              />
            </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Also for PrivateRoute, I am using this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Now issue here is, isLoggedIn() work, but this is how.

I will got `/` and it will redirect me to `/login` and then isLoggedIn get called?

it will take me to back `/`, but when I go to `/stats`, it will take me back to `login` and then again to `/`, not to `/stats`??

How I can go back to the page I started with? without auth?

Comment: You don't pass the `auth` prop to `PrivateRoute` component, which makes it not possible to check `auth.isAuthenticated`

Comment: question is not that: Question is how to get back to the route from where I started without auth

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you want to redirect to the previous page after a login is done?

Comment: I want to redirect to the page where I start as unauthenticated such as '/abc' it goes to /login after auth it should go to /abc not /

Comment: Then you should add an explicit redirect in your Login component, after an authentication takes place

Comment: Yes thats the question right there how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an additional state for undetermined auth state and then render the Router only after the auth state in already known.
This will prevent you from premature redirecting.